RavenDb - getting name of a collection
It seems RavenDb pluralizes object names when storing them. So a PhoneBook becomes PhoneBooks, and PhoneBookCategory becomes PhoneBookCategories.
For any ByQueryOperation, if I write the query, I have to address the name of the collection. E.g. here for a bulk delete:
var queryParameters = new Raven.Client.Parameters
    {
        {
            "ids", ids.ToArray()
        }
    };
var q = new IndexQuery
{
    Query = "from {collectionName} u where id(u) in ($ids)",
    QueryParameters = queryParameters
};
DeleteByQueryOperation op = new DeleteByQueryOperation(q);

Now, how can I make sure I get the correct collectionName?

The metadata of a document contains the property @collection, which determines to which collection the document belongs to.
You can get the metadata of a document by calling, for example:
var employee = session.Load<Employee>("employees/1-A");
var metadata = session.Advanced.GetMetadataFor(employee);
var collection = metadata["@collection"];


Document metadata - RavenDB Book:
https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/2-zero-to-ravendb#document-metadata
Get & Modify metadata:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/Csharp/client-api/session/how-to/get-and-modify-entity-metadata

Note:
You can customize the collection name generated for a given class type by using the FindCollectionName convention:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/csharp/client-api/configuration/conventions#findcollectionname
How to set conventions:
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/latest/csharp/client-api/configuration/conventions#how-to-set-conventions

Is there a way to get the metadata without having to extract a document? In my use case where I'm deleting, it would be rather redundant to first fetch an item before doing a bulk delete. Right now I'd fetch it and cache it, but it's still a request I'd rather not have to make.

Well, if you customize the collection name as mentioned above, then you wouldn't need to retrieve the metadata to verify the collection name being used because you control it.

I did the customization. But couldn't I just call DocumentConventions.DefaultGetCollectionName(typeof(Employee)) to get the name?

1. Yes, you can call DocumentConventions.DefaultGetCollectionName(typeof(Employee)) to get the collection name.
2. But - better to call store.Conventions.GetCollectionName(typeof(Employee)). See implementation in:  https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/3041a597936cda46421c6c3580695e0859f9fb33/src/Raven.Client/Documents/Conventions/DocumentConventions.cs#L1166
3. This is still to be documented under issue: https://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RDoc-2612/C-Add-missing-conventions-in-Configuration-Conventions
